# Email Validation in Checkout Page in Magento

Tags: validation, magento, email, email-validation, php

I need to change the email validation of Magento's Checkout page (Checkout as a Guest).

The problem is the default style of input box contains character support only. When I tried to input email with numbers, it doesn't accept and display number.

So I need a proper validation with regard to its email. The email address input box should also accept characters with numbers.

Thanks,

I tried to check this Code:

File location: **onepage/billing.phtml**

```
 <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

File location: **validation.js**

```
['validate-email', 'Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.', function (v) {
                //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /\w{1,}[@][\w\-]{1,}([.]([\w\-]{1,})){1,3}$/.test(v)
                //return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^[\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9][\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9\.]{1,30}[\!\#$%\*/?|\^\{\}`~&\'\+\-=_a-z0-9]@([a-z0-9_-]{1,30}\.){1,5}[a-z]{2,4}$/i.test(v)
                return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9,!\#\$%&'\*\+\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*@([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z0-9-]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*\.(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]){2,})$/i.test(v)
            }],
```

Comment: What email-id are you entering ?

Comment: The email-id sample123@yahoo.com is good to go when checkout as Guest.
The input type should be
<input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="" title="Email Address" class="input-text validate-email required-entry validation-passed">
Have you made any custom changes in validation script ?

Comment: Still not working. I think the software vendor customized it. I used to check the validation.js as well as the billing.phtml file; Can't figure out the code he overridden. Aside from this, Is there any way out to override the validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. 
File Location: template/webtexgiftregisrty/billing.phtml

On th field box of email address, insert the string data types inside the class validation.

Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="string input-block-level input-text validate-email required-entry billing-email" />
```

Comment: Thanks Cherry, The code is now working! Many Thanks. Marked as answer!